# Find Postal Code | Zipcode using Google map geocoding reverse

Tags: javascript, php, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

Find Postal Code | Zipcode using Google map geocoding reverse.

I want this functionality. Please check screenshot.

https://snag.gy/IAaZmr.jpg

I just want to fetch pincode for the ewspective google location using google api geocoding

Comment: Please post code that you have tried to write.

Answer (score 0):

```
function callZipAPI(addSearchZip){    
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var zipCode = null;

geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addSearchZip }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        //var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        //var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        var addressComponent = results[0].address_components;            
        for (var x = 0 ; x < addressComponent.length; x++) {
            var chk = addressComponent[x];
            if (chk.types[0] == 'postal_code') {
                zipCode = chk.long_name;
            }
        }
        if (zipCode) {
            alert(zipCode);
        }
        else {
            alert('No result found!!');
        }
    } else {            
        alert('Enter proper address!!');
    }
});}
```